# Wrong sources.list entry after adding resilio sync repository

Tags: apt

I followed this [Guide](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924-Installing-Sync-package-on-Linux) to install `resilio sync` on my RPI1.
Installation works but I get an Error if I run `sudo apt-get update`.

```
W: Failed to fetch
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/InRelease 
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch
http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease    
Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages' in Release
file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

This is the sources.list entries I have:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

And my RPI1 info from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7

Hardware        : BCM2835
Revision        : 0002
Serial          : 000000002d32faa1
```

Comment: Welcom to stackExchange, can you edit your post and add the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list`file ?